# Find a string enclosed in spaces or coming from the beginning or end with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How can I match some string enclosed in spaces or coming from the beginning or end?

I need match for `-someword` in the following sentences: `word1 -someword word2`, `-someword word1`, `word1 -someword`,  `-someword`. And don't need match in the sentences: `s-someword`, `-somewordd`

I tried grep the above with regex `grep -r [^ ]-someword[$ ]` (i.e before `-someword` must be a space or `-someword` must start the sentence, after `-someword` must be a space or `-someword` must end the sentence), but it finds nothing.

Comment: When you say "space" in your question, do you mean just the blank character generated by pressing the space bar on your keyboard or do you mean any white space character including tabs?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
grep -w -e -someword
```

From `man grep`:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> ```
>           Select only those lines containing matches that form whole
>           words.  The test is that the matching substring must
>           either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a
>           non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be
>           either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word
>           constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are
>           letters, digits, and the underscore.  This option has no
>           effect if -x is also
> ```

Please note that it would also match `-someword` if it's surrounded by some other non alphanumeric character except for white spaces, such as `#` or `,`. If you want to ensure it's surrounded **only** by spaces or beginning/end of line, you can use:

```
egrep '(^|[[:space:]])-someword([[:space:]]|$)'

# Which is equivalent to:

grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])-someword([[:space:]]|$)'

# Or without extended regex:

grep '\(^\|[[:space:]]\)-someword\([[:space:]]\|$\)'
```

Comment: You may also want to use `-F` to avoid using the query string as a regular expression.

Comment: @Kusalananda if they did that then they couldn't add boundaries to avoid matching `-someword` with non-blank, non-word-constituent chars on either side, e.g. `-someword-`

Comment: @EdMorton I was thinking about their first `grep` command. `-w` can be combined with `-F`. I didn't even try to read the other expressions.

Comment: @Kusalananda Right, `-Fw` would be an improvement over just `-w` but they actually need `-w` without `-F` and some additional constructs in the regexp to do what the OP asked for - `before -someword must be a space or -someword must start the sentence, after -someword must be a space or -someword must end the sentence`

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, you might well be correct. To explicitly conform to that specification, `-wF` would not be enough.

Comment: @aviro `egrep` has been deprecated for about 15+ years (since 2007 IIRC) in favor of `grep -E`, no reason to include it in any answer.

Comment: There's no alternation in standard BRE, so that last one with `\|` will only work in some systems. Also since `grep -E` _is_ standard, there's no reason to use nonstandard variants like that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following to avoid complicated regular expressions.  It matches any line that has `-someword` at the start with a space after it, `-someword` somewhere in the middle with spaces on either side, or `-someword` at the end with a space before it:

```bash
grep -e '^-someword ' -e ' -someword ' -e ' -someword$'
```

This all assumes that `-someword` is a string that does not contain any characters that are special in regular expressions. If it does, the string must be rewritten to match these literal characters, e.g.,  by escaping them in the pattern.

If you also want to match lines containing nothing but the string `-someword`, add `-e '^-someword$'`.

If you by "space" mean "a blank character", which would include both tabs and spaces, then change the literal spaces in the pattern with `[[:blank:]]`.  Would you need to match a wider variety of space-like characters, such as vertical tabs and carriage returns, use `[[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: FWIW I find `grep -E '(^| )-someword( |$)'` less complicated than `grep -e '^-someword ' -e ' -someword ' -e ' -someword$'`. Neither would match a tab before/after `-somespace` though.

Comment: @EdMorton Depends on who you are, I suppose. Matching three plain patterns seems less complicated to me than a single patterns with two alternations containing anchors in it. Also, was tab supposed to be allowed?

Comment: Agreed and understood. The OP said `space` which is ambiguous but I don't see anything to tell me for sure that it can't include tabs or any other chars in the `[:space:]` POSIX character class (or at least `[:blank:]`).

Comment: I've now [asked the OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741034/find-a-string-enclosed-in-spaces-or-coming-from-the-beginning-or-end-with-grep/741475?noredirect=1#comment1408699_741034) what they mean by "space".

Answer (score 1):

The Regex pattern for this is (https://regexr.com/7b8g0):

```
(\s|^)-someword(\s|$)
```

A lot of shells freak out about these `()\|` so you'll have to fiddle with quotes and escapes a bit. For example fish seems to like `\\s` but zsh likes `\s`.

With ripgrep and fish, it's pretty easy to implement:

```
$ bat word.txt --style=numbers
   1 word1 -someword word2
   2 -someword word1
   3 word1 -someword
   4 -someword
   5 s-someword
   6 -somewordd
   7 \s-someword

$ bat word.txt | rg '(\\s|^)-someword(\\s|$)' --only-matching --line-number
1: -someword
2:-someword
3: -someword
4:-someword

$ bat word.txt | rg '(\\s|^)-someword(\\s|$)' --line-number -v
5:s-someword
6:-somewordd
7:\s-someword
```

(I added `\s-someword` and `-v` to address some concerns in comments.)

Note that the spaces become part of the match. To fix that in the regex, you'd have to add a capturing group around `-someword` (easy) and then then tell `rg` to return the first group (pffft...).

Because grep is ancient it won't process this "advanced" regex syntax by default. You need to add `-E`.

```
$ bat word.txt | grep -E '(\\s|^)(-someword)(\\s|$)' -n
1:word1 -someword word2
2:-someword word1
3:word1 -someword
4:-someword

$ bat word.txt | grep -v -E '(\\s|^)(-someword)(\\s|$)' -n
5:s-someword
6:-somewordd
7:\s-someword
```

Frankly, if you live in a year starting with 2, you should probably alias `grep` to `grep -E` anyway. Or just use `rg`.

Comment: Note that the pattern `\\s` would match the literal string `\s` (maybe it's a feature of the`fish` shell I don't understand that makes it work for you, if so you should point this out), and that `\s` is a pattern similar to `[[:space:]]`, but only if you use a non-standard `grep` implementation that understands Perl-compatible regular expressions (or a subset thereof).  The regular expression that `grep` uses with `-E` are called POSIX extended regular expressions.

Comment: @Kusalananda "the pattern `\\s` would match the literal string `\s`" - just tried it, it doesn't.

Comment: "The regular expression that `grep` uses with `-E` are called POSIX extended regular expressions." - indeed, the curious would also discover this tidbit in `man grep`. I try to avoid cluttering my brain with unnecessary trivia.

Comment: @Kusalananda Also, I can't comment on your answer because of the stupid restrictions on new accounts, but your version has a bug and won't match a line with only `-someword`. I think you need another `-e '^-someword$'`.

Comment: I can't get `\\s` to match a space with `grep -E` using FreeBSD `grep` nor with GNU `grep`. Not even `pcregrep` recognises `\\s` as the same as `\s`. It only ever matches the literal string `\s`.

Comment: I interpreted the question as requiring a space before or after the string, but you may be right that they want to also match lines containing nothing but the string (there was no such example).

Comment: Why do you mention `fish` in your answer, if I may ask?

Comment: @Kusalananda Seems like `\\s` works for me even with grep. I edited the answer. As for why it works for me but not for you,  lol.

Comment: The reason I specify fish is because I suspect not all shells treat quoting and special characters equally, and I'm too lazy to check it right now. But I figured I might as well give a heads up to whoever finds this on google later.

Comment: So depending on how `fish` works, your shell may actually convert `\\s` into `\s` before calling the `grep` utility. That's what I'm thinking. Introducing an extra level of evaluation, so to speak.

Comment: Sounds plausible. I just tried in zsh and it has to be `\s` not `\\s` there.